# Applications of "Seemingly Impossible Functional Programs"

Tags: computability, topology

What are some practical applications (existing or potential) for Martin Escardo's ["Seemingly Impossible Functional Programs"?](http://math.andrej.com/2007/09/28/seemingly-impossible-functional-programs/)

For starters, [here are a few from](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/.talks/popl2012/escardo-popl2012.pdf):

- Alex Simpson’s Lazy functional algorithms for exact real functionals.
  Compute maximum value and integral of a real function, with real numbers
  represented as infinite sequences of digits.
- Verification of real-number programs by checking infinitely many cases.